# Am I getting an SQL syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, utf-8

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contracts` (
  `contractId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL COMMENT,
  `title` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `contractText` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `contractState` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '1-Nepatvirtinta, 2- patvirtinta, 3-  panaikinta, 4- atmesta',
  PRIMARY KEY (`contractId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `title` (`title`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_lithuanian_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;



INSERT INTO `contracts` (`contractId`, `username`, `title`, `contractText`, `date`,   `contractState`) VALUES


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `username` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `usergroup` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT,
  `name` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `state` tinyint(4) NOT NULL COMMENT,
 PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_lithuanian_ci;
```

When running this query on the SQL server, I am getting the following error:

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
>     `title` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
>     `contractText` text CHAR' at line 13

why this is coming up?

Answer (score 1):

You did not add a comment to the `username` column.

```
`username` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL COMMENT  ,
        add one here---------------------------------------^
```

or remove the `COMMENT` keyword

Answer (score 1):

in this line

```
      `username` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL COMMENT 'comment',
```

add some comment in for COMMENT or Remove Comment. Below is working code.

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contracts` (
`contractId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL COMMENT 'comment',
`title` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`contractText` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`date` datetime NOT NULL,
`contractState` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '1-Nepatvirtinta, 2- patvirtinta, 3-    
 panaikinta, 4- atmesta',
 PRIMARY KEY (`contractId`),
 UNIQUE KEY `title` (`title`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_lithuanian_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just fix your table creation to add explicit comment or remove COMMENT keyword if it is not needed.

Try modify it to become:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contracts` (
  `contractId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL COMMENT 'add explicit comment her',
  `title` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `contractText` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `contractState` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '1-Nepatvirtinta, 2- patvirtinta, 3- panaikinta, 4- atmesta',
  PRIMARY KEY (`contractId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `title` (`title`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_lithuanian_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `comment` from this line:

```
`username` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL , //COMMENT
```